# I might have incorrectly answered a question about biometric collection

Tags: schengen-visas, biometric-passports

I recently applied for a Schengen Visa(France) at the VFS office in SF. When the gentleman at the counter asked me if I had previously had my biometrics information taken I replied Yes because I vaguely remembered having my fingerprints scanned at the Swiss consulate since it was an in-person interview but now I am not sure(yes, it was not wise of me to say Yes in the first place). I did so because I had previously gotten a Schengen visa from the Swiss consulate in SF in August 2017. I traveled to Switzerland in September 2017. 
The Remarks on my old Schengen visa say **Tourisme** instead of **VIS** which would be the case for a biometric visa. I am now a bit worried if this will cause any delays in my visa application or possibly a denial. Is there a way to fix this by calling the VFS office or rather just wait for an update. 
I am hoping that because I was able to travel to the Schengen region without any problems and it has not been 59 months since my last visa was issues my biometrics information must be in the VIS database.

Comment: "Tourisme" is completely orthogonal to "VIS."

Comment: *Alea iacta est*, you cannot change what you did. The question (and answers) will not change the outcome. Relax and wait for news.

Answer (score 4):

Update - I got my visa approval in a week.